# Value of type 'GADMobileAds' has no member 'start'

Tags: swift, admob

I'm trying to add a googleAdMob to my app , and I want to start shared instance of GADMobileAds . but it tells me Value of type 'GADMobileAds' has no member 'start'.
Hint: 
my Xcode version is 10.1, swift version is 4, iOS target 10 or more, Add appid to GADApplicationIdentifier in plist and I got it with cocoaPod.

here is my code

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        return true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you installed outdated version of `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK`. Try `pod update Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK`.

Comment: I tried it again but pod told me it Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.37.0) and it's the last version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see from AdMob's [release note](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes) that the latest version is `7.43.0`, and I believe the `start` method is added after version `7.37.0`.
You could run `pod install --repo-update` to update your local pod or explicit set AdMob version by `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.43.0'`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using the older version of `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` library you need to update it with the latest one which is mention on **CocoaPod** Installation guide.

> **Installation Guide for Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK**
>
> You want to add pod
>   'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.43' similar to the following to your
>   Podfile:
>
> `target 'MyApp' do
>   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.43' 
>   end`
>
> Then run a pod install inside your terminal, or from CocoaPods.app.
>
> **Alternatively to give it a test run, run the command:**
>
> pod try Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK

Ref Link: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK

Hope this will helps!

Answer (score -1):

make sure you have the pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' in your podfile
and dont forget about:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

I just tried it, it works

Comment: try reinstalling or updating the pod.